# Using Single Online/Offline button for multiple skills in Live Agent

Tags: liveagent

I have setup and tested a button with a single skill successfully. The button shows up online when a user with that skill is logged into live agent.

But, if I assign another skill to the button and have a user with that skill login to live agent the button goes offline. Is it not possible to have multiple skills assigned to a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem today. The explanation is in the following article:

[Live Agent Chat Buttons with Multiple Skills](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Live-Agent-Chat-Buttons-with-Multiple-Skills&type=1)

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that I wanted to share. It has taken a bit to get here.

You can use the "fallback" option found late in the developers guide. My steps were:

1. Create a "catch-all" live agent button. I add all profiles that will have access to live agent. Use this button as the one actually displayed on your website. This is the best optoin I have found with this concept to control the display of your chat presence. This will not actially be the button/skill the visitor will chat to. the following steps will override the catch-all button.
2. Create buttons for each skill/department you want to route to
3. Create a pre-chat form. This form should have a select picklist with options that look something like this:

> ```
> <pre>Department:
> <select name="liveagent.prechat.buttons">  
> <!-- Values are
> LiveChatButton and/or User IDs. -->  
> <option value="573D01234567890">Billing</option> 
> <option value="005D01234567890">Sales</option>  
> <option value="005D01234567890">Support</option>
> </select>
> </pre>
> ```

*See the developers guide for more detail on creating a prechat form.*
You are done!

One potential issue with this method is that a skill in the picklist may not be available. Either this will be acceptable for you or you can use the method of specifying 2 values, A primary and the "fallback" which this sample in the developer guide is really meant for.

Comment: Using this fallback option. Would there be 2 pre-chat forms? One that has the picklist for chat buttons and another with the ACTUAL prechat form?

Comment: Also "Create a "catch-all" live agent button. I add all profiles that will have access to live agent." How are you assigning profiles to buttons?

Comment: could you provide a full code example of how you implemented this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple skills can be assigned to a button.

I have done below coding and it is working perfectly.

```
<html><h1> Customer Portal </h1><a id="liveagent_button_online_573q00000008OVs" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('573q00000008OVs')">Online Chat</a><div id="liveagent_button_offline_573q00000008OVs" style="display: none;">Offline Chat</div><script type="text/javascript">if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('573q00000008OVs', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_573q00000008OVs'));
liveagent.showWhenOffline('573q00000008OVs', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_573q00000008OVs'));});</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/35.0/deployment.js'></script>
```

```
liveagent.init('https://d.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572q00000008OOS', '00Dq00000004Z2R');</script></html>
```

Comment: Is this your Chat Button and Deployment code? I understand how to create the buttons. But I have found that even user with each skill assigned being online does not change my button to online.